# Scale and interpolate an array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, interpolation, scaling

I have a simple 1D array with some numbers (which do NOT represent anything that have to do with an image), and four elements containing e.g.

```
1 5 9 13
```

Now I want to scale this array by a factor of 3 to a size of 12 elements and interpolate the contained numbers in the new array elements linearly. So after this scale-operation the new array would contain for this example the following values:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
```

My question: is there any standard C/C++ function/library/code available for this performing such an operation with different array sizes and factors? This sounds for me like it could be a standard problem where one would not have to re-invent the wheel again.

Thanks!

Comment: Get a line segment(`y=m*x + c`) which fits the original array and then use it to get the value of transformed array `a[i] = (i/L, m * i/L + c)`

Comment: I don't know about such a "standard function" but notice that there is some problem with your question. The scaled array has 13 elements but the text says 12 elements.

Comment: @4386427 He counts from 0.

Comment: @V87, what is the use of the comma operator?

Comment: @v78 I know how a linear interpolation is done, my question is more, if there is a generic function/library available which scales and interpolates to and from every size. as this seems to be a standard, non-exotic problem I would guess there are already solutions available for this!? And your code example does not look lie C or C++

Comment: In C, use `realloc` and that's about it. Better yet, allocate sufficient memory from the start, since `realloc` calls are slow and wasteful.

Comment: @4386427 the array is also scaled by a factor of 4, not 3. Each element is replaced by 4 elements (except the last).

Comment: @Elmi That's the function you are looking for though. There's no standard function to interpolate numbers, you have to code that yourself or find some lib.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, I just listed out both the x and Y coordinates for `ith` index.

Comment: I haven't answered anything, just posted comments. The answer to your question appears to simply be "no, there is no such function".

Comment: Such a function would be more appropriate in a "utilities" library than a standard one. Once it is added, there would need to be a raft of other array functions, such as finding min, max, average, mean etc, and one version for each data type. The OP mentions "not images" but the idea would naturally be extended to cater for 2D arrays too.

Comment: Yes, there are libraries for such scaling (it's pretty useful in audio conversions, for example).  But finding or recommending libraries is specifically off-topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++20, there is [std::lerp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lerp) to do linear interpolation.

But you have to call it manually after resizing the array. Something like:

```
std::vector<int> grow(const std::vector<int>& v, std::size_t k)
{
    if (v.empty()) {
        return {};   
    }

    std::vector<int> res(v.size() * (k - 1) + 1);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i + 1 < v.size(); ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j != k; ++j) {
            res[i * k + j] = std::lerp(v[i], v[i + 1], float(j) / k);
        }
    }
    res.back() = v.back();
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d767bc005741632)

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard library currently contains no such functionality. There is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1385r2.html) to add linear algebra support, but I see nothing related to interpolation there, and in any case it's likely to be several years before this bears any fruit.

Depending on the type of interpolation that you'd like to do you could look at [eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/structEigen_1_1SplineFitting.html) and [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/math/doc/html/interpolation.html).

Answer (score -1):

How do you want to deal with "before first value" and "after last value"? There are 3 possibilities:

a) Suppress them. In this case `1, 4` scaled by a factor of 3 would become `1, 2, 3, 4`.

b) Assume the data wraps around. In this case `1, 4` scaled by a factor of 3 would become `2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3`.

c) Assume "before" and "after" are a default value like zero. In this case `1, 4` scaled by a factor of 3 would become `0.66, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2.66`.

How do you want to deal with rounding? For example (for integers), `1, 2` scaled by a factor of 2 (using "a)" above) would be `1, 1.5, 2` but `1.5` isn't an integer and is "equally close" to both `1` and `2`. There are 5 possibilities here (round to negative infinity, round to zero, round away from zero, round to even, round to positive infinity).

Now...

Let's assume there are 4 integer data types (8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit) and 3 floating point data types (32-bit, 64-bit and 80-bit) and therefore there are "`7*3*5= 105`" possible permutations of data type, scaling method and rounding.

**Would you want to add 105 different functions to the C standard library to cover all of these permutations?**

If you do; then what about scaling 2D arrays, and scaling "array of structure/bitfield", and ...? Surely these things are all more frequently desired.

**How many millions of rarely needed functions would need to be added to the standard library before scaling 2D arrays of primitive numbers becomes the "next least infrequently desired" feature in a library that currently doesn't even support extremely basic stuff (like `beep(frequency)`)?**